# how to fix Android Native Crash from libc.so, unity project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
Native StackTrace:

Thread 0 (crashed)
0   libc.so                            0x00000075054e7c24 <symbols missing for uuid: 9d24735c2e77ed9a6f043f56b84eff8d> 
1   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000719b0be824 GC_unmap (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\extra/..\os_dep.c:2577)
2   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000719b0be754 GC_unmap_old (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\extra/..\allchblk.c:435)
3   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000719b0c039c GC_finish_collection (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\extra/..\alloc.c:1154)
4   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000719b0c05d8 GC_collect_a_little_inner (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\extra/..\alloc.c:695)
5   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000719b0bf804 GC_collect_a_little (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\extra/..\alloc.c:719)
6   libunity.so                        0x000000719e671d94 GarbageCollector::CollectIncremental(unsigned long) 
7   libunity.so                        0x000000719e51b8e0 TimeManager::EndSyncFrame(TimeManager::SyncBehaviour) 
8   libunity.so                        0x000000719ebc6f20 GfxDeviceClient::WaitForPendingPresent() 
9   libunity.so                        0x000000719ebc6e1c GfxDeviceClient::BeginFrame() 
10  libunity.so                        0x000000719e5cd7f4 PlayerRender(bool) 
11  libunity.so                        0x000000719e5c9f74 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) 
12  libunity.so                        0x000000719e5c9fa8 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) 
13  libunity.so                        0x000000719e5ca1ec PlayerLoop() 
14  libunity.so                        0x000000719e6e2154 UnityPlayerLoop() 
15  libunity.so                        0x000000719e6f7604 nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*) 
16  base.odex                          0x00000072036238fc <symbols missing for uuid: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
```

Hello.

This is what I received using the Unity Crash Report.

But it's my first time using it, so I don't know exactly why these messages crash.

Can anyone explain what caused the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Disabling incremental garbage collector "fixed" this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).